# Face Detection(Haar) without opencv

Tags: c, opencv, face-detection

I am currently working on a face detection program using haar classifiers(I am using the sample program that comes with opencv installation).What i need to do is to extract this code out of opencv and make the code work without opencv libraries i.e. without opencv installed on both windows and linux desktops.I have been trying to do this for a while but with no success.Any suggestions on how to do this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: It might be easier for you to re-write the whole stuff from scratch in this case. cvHaarDetectObjects() relies heavily on many OpenCV utility classes, you will have to "extract" them as well.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need to do that?

Comment: There is face detector already built in OpenCV which runs real time on desktop.I expect it (face or car detection) to be running very slow on beagle board. The target of this would be to pull out that code. Use DSP present on beagle board to see how fast it can run on the embedded platform.

Comment: I'm tring to implement the viola jones algorithom over cuda technologoy , must say it's almost unbearable working with opencv library and trying to change it. I don't believe there is an option taking the code out of opencv, I have tried that and faild.using the dll is not enoght.if you find a solution for this , please let me know shaharsarshalom@gmail.com

Comment: any success with the implementation?

Answer (score 4):

OpenCV is a very sophisticated imaging library. The sample program will use the library(!),  you cannot simply run the code without the library.

Answer (score 2):

You won't get any performance benefits running "copy-pasted" OpenCV code on BeagleBoard's DSP.

1. C64x is a fixed point DSP, floating point support is done in software. So you will need to convert OpenCV code to fixed point, to use full power of DSP
2. Main bottleneck of cvHaarDetectObjects() is not calculations, but uncached memory access during feature calculation, so you won't get any benefits in running it on DSP as-is.

What you can try is to port functions like cvIntegral() - they might be accelerated on DSP.

Check this:

http://elinux.org/BeagleBoard/GSoC/2010_Projects/OpenCV

http://code.google.com/p/opencv-dsp-acceleration/

http://www.computer-vision-software.com/blog/2009/04/fixing-opencv/

http://pramodpoudel.blogspot.com/

And this - running Viola-Jones on ARM7

http://cmucam.org/wiki/viola-jones (especially CC3 Face Detector document)

http://cmucam.org/browser/trunk/projects/viola-jones